# Google Maps Geocoding finding wrong address

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to figure out what I can do to get the proper geocoding information for an address in my system.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=570 E 900 N, Denver, IN 46926-9309&key=XXXXXX

Everything that I try comes back with just Denver, CO (with no address).

I've tried adding bounds to the request, with no change.
The address is properly formatted and verified by smarty.com.

Google Maps itself can find the address, and doesn't appear to alter it at all.
https://www.google.com/maps/place/570+E+900+N,+Denver,+IN+46926/@40.8960543,-86.068729,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x881412cc33d8ac83:0xd68874c092ad499a!8m2!3d40.8960503!4d-86.0661541!16s%2Fg%2F11csm6ldyr

Any other ideas?

Comment: Google Maps and the Google Maps API are different things.  That address (570 E 900 N, Denver, IN) is in the Places API database: placeId: ChIJg6zYM8wSFIgRmkmtksB0iNY [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vwu26pch/1/) and can be found using autocomplete: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/v53pwtzs/2/), however that address doesn't seem to be in the Geocoder database (it returns the location of Denver,IN): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k2azj1fm/), which implies it is a data problem with the geocoder.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a valid issue to be [reported in the issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/support#issue-tracker).

Geocoding "570 E 900 N, Denver, IN 46926" returns only the city of Denver, CO, USA. That's a partial result, indicating the Geocoding API did not understand the query well enough. However, the correct result [ChIJg6zYM8wSFIgRmkmtksB0iNY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJg6zYM8wSFIgRmkmtksB0iNY) is found by geocoding slightly less abbreviated queries:

- [570 E 900 N, Denver, Indiana 46926](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D570%2520E%2520900%2520N%252C%2520Denver%252C%2520Indiana%252046926)
- [570 E 900 N, Denver, IN 46926, USA](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D570%2520E%2520900%2520N%252C%2520Denver%252C%2520IN%252046926%252C%2520USA)